# Invoke Put Odata Controller Method through Code in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata

I have a Odata controller class in my project, and I need to invoke PUT controller method from other piece of code.

My PUT controller method's declaration looks like this, which accepts two parameters and class object.

```
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromODataUri] string name, [FromODataUri] string version, Product product)
```

I can invoke this method through fiddler with this URL, this works fine, now I need to invoke this Put controller method through code.

```
https://127.0.0.1/odata/ControllerName(name='ProductName',version=1)
```

The code, I have written so far works fine with Put method and accepting one Odata param from URL, but not sure how to make it work with two parameters.

```
Container container = new ProductService.Container(baseUri);
container.AttachTo("Products", product);
container.UpdateObject(product);
container.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);
```

Here, this invokes Put Controller with one parameter, passing parameter value equal to Primary Key but as I have two primary keys and same two parameters accepting Put Controller Method.

How should I invoke Put controller method from C# code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar sample project https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v3/ODataCompositeKeySample/ There are POST, PATCH methods:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutPerson([FromODataUri] string firstName, [FromODataUri] string lastName, Person person)
{
    _repo.UpdateOrAdd(person);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

and an example of invoking PATCH:

```
private static void PatchPerson()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Patch Person");
    Container c = new Container();
    var person = c.People.Where(p => p.FirstName == "Eric" && p.LastName == "Smith").Single();
    person.Age = 9;
    c.UpdateObject(person);
    c.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.PatchOnUpdate);
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}, {1}'s age is changed to {2}", person.FirstName, person.LastName, person.Age);
    GetPeople();
}
```

Please make sure there is a composite key in your entity, just the same as:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```